# Free C pointer when collected by GC

Tags: go

I have a package that interfaces with a C library. Now I need to store a pointer to a C struct in the Go struct

```
type A struct {
  s *C.struct_b
}
```

Obviously this pointer needs to be freed before the struct is collected by the GC. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing to do is when possible copy the C struct into go controlled memory.

```
var ns C.struct_b
ns = *A.s
A.s = &ns
```

Obviously, that won't work in all cases. C.struct_b may be too complicated or shared with something still in C code. In this case, you need to create a .Free() or .Close() method (whichever makes more sense) and document that the user of your struct must call it. In Go, a Free method should always be safe to call. For example, after free is run, be sure to set A.s = nil so that if the user calls Free twice, the program does not crash.

There is also a way to create finalizers. See another answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812524/727643). However, they may not always run and if garbage is created fast enough, it is very possible that the creation of garbage will out pace collection. This should be considered as a supplement to having a Free/Close method and not a replacement.

Comment: No, just very few instances are created. I think I'll go with the finalizer approach, because the struct is opaque (imported from a library) and I don't know how complex it is.

Comment: I recommend you provide a .Free() method and if possible use it. As I said, finalizers are a backup, they should not be the only thing you rely on.

Comment: Yep, that's how I did it. I have a `Destroy()` method and use the finalizer as a backup.